# Cast object into vector's const_iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, const-iterator

Hi I have a function which takes `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` as parameter.

Question is:

How can I cast standalone object of type T, into iterator, so I can use it as an argument?

Comment: Is T an iterable type?  Why not make your function a template function were the template type names the type of iterator required?  Like `template <typname FowardIterator> print(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {}`

Comment: There is no way to do that (in a safe and portable manner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"How can I cast standalone object of type T, into iterator, so I can use it as an argument?"*

You cannot. That *standalone object* needs to be stored in an appropriate container. Only containers provide creation of iterators.

Comment: So you suggest the best/simplest way to do it is to put this object into container and then create iterator?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to cast an arbitrary object type T to `std::vector::const_iterator`.

Assuming the object is a `std::vector<T>`, you can use the `std::vector::cbegin` or `std::vector::cend` functions to get a `std::vector::const_iterator`.